# Rails datetime input and microseconds

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with that has a datetime to store both time and date. I am using a calendar that support both, problem is that rails won't update the form sometimes:.

For example, setting ste start_date = 01/14/2011 12:00
Does not work

By contrast start_date=01/11/2011 00:00
Nothing else changes

So the problem is I was sending mm/dd/yy and rails uses dd/mm/yy
I fixed using JQuery

```
$('#start_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$('#end_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Comment: It would be good to show the code itself

Comment: there is just nothing very interesting i'll add it though

Comment: ok just found the problem, rails is /day/month/year my calendar is /month/day/year

Comment: that's sort of right, but not quite accurate -- it's only because you are using slashes. see the answer i just posted for a more in-depth reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.parse` uses a heuristic algorithm to guess about how it should parse dates.

Generally, using slashes like "01/11/2010" triggers it to parse as "MM/DD/YYYY" while using dashes "01-11-2010" triggers it to parse as "DD-MM-YYYY". So your input above needs to either pass dashes instead of slashes, or switch the order of the day and the month.